# how to get price in multi-store view in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, multistore, product-prices

my site is running in multi-store view using store code in url .
now
**1 > product price in GBP = 20

2 > exchange rate for USD = 1.4

3 > for usd store i want to get price including exchange rate

4 > so the price will in usd = 20*1.4 = 28**

Note:- **But when I get the price programmatically in custom.phtml file for USD store it shows GBP price**

so how to get USD price.

Comment: Have you setup curreny conversation rate from admin?

Comment: yes it is working on product page but i want to get it in custom phtml file

Comment: In your custom file, you can get product price by magento way. So you get proper price.

Comment: share the code which you try to get product price on custom page.

Comment: $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
$products = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
  $products->getPrice();

Comment: share complete code into question it self. by editing the question.

Comment: i am getting the current product using objectmanager and try to get price using above code

Answer (score 0):

You need to use code like this.

```
$OM = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$priceHelper = $OM->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data');
$productprice = $priceHelper->currency($products->getFinalPrice(), true, false);
echo $productprice;
```

Comment: If my answer help you, accept it, So it help other in community as well.